# MySQL Rating/Voting system (accurratly ordering by best rated taking into account number of votes)

Tags: mysql, math, sorting, rating, weighted-average

Let's say I have a MySQL table that is something like this:

software table:

```
id int
name text
votes int
rating int
```

Where votes would be the number of times someone has voted for that item and rating would be the average of those votes.

Example data:

```
id: 0
name: FooBar!
votes: 5
rating: 3
```

Now another user comes along and rates this a 1. How would I caculate the new rating? would be be better to just make another table and enter a new row every time someone votes like

```
id int
software_id int
score int
user_id int
```

and then calculate the re-calculate the average rating every time? I would think it would take a toll on the server.

Second question:

I'd like to be able to order the software by the highest rated but I don't want a program with an average 5 star rating but only 1 vote to rank higher than a program with an average of 4 with 893 votes. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Question 1a : How to calculate the new average rating:

```
vote count : 5
average rating: 3
```

new vote with rating of one

```
             5*3+1
 new rating= ----- = 16/6 = 8/3 = 2.666.. 
               6
```

You must take the "weight" (1/6 of all votes) of the new vote and the old average (5 occurences out of 6) into account .. the old average 3 is counted 5 times, the new rating once => 5*3 +1= 16. Then you divide by the total of 6 votes received.

### Question 1b: Should you store votes?

really depends if you expect to be gamedor not

I suggest you do it.

Comment: hence the formula is {average_rating = (old_vote_count * old_rating + new_rating)/(old_vote_count + 1)}